# How do you upload a font to your webpage (is the server needed)?

Tags: html, css, flask, fonts, server

I am trying to upload a custom font to my site, but keep failing and I am not sure if I need to add routing in my server for it to work (I am using python flask).

The font is in `static/fonts/Sofia_Handwritten.otf` in my computer, before launching the server.

And the way I am trying to access it is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Sofia_Handwritten";
    src: url("fonts/Sofia_Handwritten.otf");
}

#greeter {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Sofia_Handwritten';
}
```

But no matter what the font doesn't display.

The server replies with 200, so it;s finding it just fine.

Edit:
The error was in the file itself.

Comment: You say the file is `Sofia_Handwritten.css` but your looking for `Sofia_Handwritten.otf` when you try to access it.

Comment: I just don;t know how to type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @font-face should be in your `static/fonts/Sofia_Handwritten.css`. After doing so, you go to your HTML and add something like this:

```
<link href="static/fonts/Sofia_Handwritten.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and then you will be able to use your font.